# How to "properly" integrate a derivative, and undoing the product rule

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I ran into a confusing issue regarding the product rule and un-doing it. Given that $y$ is a function of $t$, taking the derivative of $e^{t/2}y$ yields the following:
$$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{t/2}y)$$
$$e^{t/2}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{1}{2}e^{t/2}y$$

this is all well and good by the product rule, but if you try to integrate it again something strange happens:
$$\int{(e^{t/2}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{1}{2}e^{t/2}y)}{dt}$$
$$\int{(e^{t/2}\frac{dy}{dt}){dt}+\int{(\frac{1}{2}e^{t/2}y)}{dt}}$$
$$\int{e^{t/2}}{dy}+e^{t/2}y+C$$
$$e^{t/2}y+e^{t/2}y + C$$
$$2e^{t/2}+C$$
$$2e^{t/2}y\mathrel{{=}\llap{/}}e^{t/2}y  $$

so what gives? is there something illegal about where I cancel the $dt$'s and integrate with respect to $y$? I can't think of anything else that would cause the product rule to be unreversible...

Comment: the second line (just after applying the product rule) is the LHS of a diff eq though. Surely that $2$ would do something to throw off my solution wouldn't it? In the text book im using, they just use the "reverse product rule" to get $e^{t/2}y + C$. This then leads to a clean solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can't integrate as you have done, because you have forgotten that $y=y(t)$.  Instead, use integration by parts:

$$\int (e^{t/2}\frac{dy}{dt})dt=ye^{t/2}-\frac{1}{2}\int (e^{t/2}y)dt$$

Plug this result in to your second line of reasoning to see the final result.

Comment: ah! thank you so much! your answer makes sense, but why then is it acceptable to do things like this? $$\frac{dy}{dt}=a$$ $$\int{\frac{dy}{dt}}{dt}=\int{a}{dt}$$ $$\int{dy}=at$$ $$y=at$$

Comment: or is this $dt$ cancelling all a bunch of nonsense i learned from some voodoo priest and its as simple as the integral of $\frac{dy}{dt}$ with respect to $t$ is just $y$? I guess that makes sense since the derivative of $y$ with respect to $t$ is $\frac{dy}{dt}$

Comment: One main difference between what you did in the question and what you've done in the comment is the function $e^{t/2}$.  Notice the following:$$\int\frac{d(e^{t/2}y)}{dt}dt=e^{t/2}y+C$$ but $$\int e^{t/2}\frac{dy}{dt}dt\ne e^{t/2}y+C.$$  In the second integral, we've treated $e^{t/2}$ as a constant, which it is not.